# url() stylus error

Tags: css, stylus

```
#logo  
 width  142px
 height 142px
 display block
 background-image url(../images/logo.png)
```

the last line prevents stylus from compiling. Why? I can't see what is wrong with my code here. Can you spot the problem.

Apparently this code is completely valid. My indents where tabs without spaces, and stylus requires a space.

Comment: Try `url('../images/logo.png')`. I have no idea what Stylus is, just a guess.

Comment: Have you tried enquoting your url?

Comment: new discovery, its the `display block`

Comment: What about using tabs instead of single spaces?

Comment: @Fresheyeball: Please submit your discovery about tabs vs spaces and mark it as the correct answer, for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently this code is completely valid. My indents where tabs without spaces, and stylus requires a space.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not due to the url but it is due to the display block, kindly en-quot block

Comment: apparently both both the url and block needed to be enquoted